# strtotime() and easter_date() won't work together

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the day after the easter date:

```
date("d-m-y", strtotime(easter_date(), '+1 day'));
```

I don't understand, the date showed is still the same, but when I try this:

```
date("d-m-y", strtotime('+1 day'));
```

It works.

How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because easter_date() produces a unix timestamp:

`1364713200`

And strtotime() is meant for this like `'today'` and `'tuesday next week'`;

If you just want to add a day to it, just add 86400 (this is how many seconds are in a day) to `easter_date()`;

So: `date("d-m-y", easter_date() + 86400);`

Comment: Thanks, it's perferct!

Answer (score 1):

The function `easter_date()` returns a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 123338898) whereas `strtotime()`'s first parameter must be a valid date/time string (e.g. 2013-05-30 23:59:59). Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Additionally, from the PHP documentation for `strtotime()`:

> Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It
>   is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and
>   later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.